# Understanding FFT output oscillation around y-axis

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, complex

I am looking at the output of the FFT and trying to understand the meaning of the real and imaginary parts of the output.
My signals (real in time) are comprised of tonal peaks and the magnitude of the FFT output reflects this. When looking at the real and imaginary parts of the FFT output, they oscillate around zero with +/- peaks around the frequencies I would expect (see figures). I was hoping someone could explain, or point me to a reference, as to why it oscillates around zero, and for the real part why it seems symmetric around the x-axis. I've read the real and imaginary parts reflect how much of they represent cosine and sine waves, but I'm struggling to understand this in the context of the actual numbers plotted and the oscillation around 0 (y-axis) near the frequencies of interest.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Real part]
[image: Imaginary part]

Comment: Notice the scale of the real part ($10^{-6}$)

Comment: Whilst the levels may be considered small, it does not take away from the behaviour it shows - the part I am interested in.

Comment: Agreed! But important to note regardless ;)